# How does the Brave browser have Chrome's dev-tools?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

Really Quick question:

Why does the Brave browser have Chrome's dev-tools?

Does this also mean that I don't need to test my website in Brave if it works in Chrome?

Thanks :)

Comment: Because it's built on chromium?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look at their [github](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop) page. Especially the tags they added:

[image]

Notice the word "[Electron](https://electron.atom.io/)", now I could explain to you what Electron is but they have an **excellent** explanation on their [Electron Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx7V9.png):

> Electron is an open source library developed by GitHub for building
> cross-platform desktop applications with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
> Electron accomplishes this by combining **Chromium** and Node.js into a
> single runtime and apps can be packaged for Mac, Windows, and Linux.

As you can see, Electron uses "Chromium". I could explain but.... you've guessed it they offer a great [explanation themselves](https://www.chromium.org/):

> The Chromium projects include Chromium and Chromium OS, the
> open-source projects behind the Google Chrome browser and Google
> Chrome OS, respectively. This site houses the documentation and code
> related to the Chromium projects and is intended for developers
> interested in learning about and contributing to the open-source
> projects.

So thats why you can access the chrome dev tools inside Brave.

#### On to your other question:

> I don't need to test in Brave if my website works in Chrome?

Yes and no, you can be fairly certain that Brave will do everything Chromium does. But in the end we can't be certain what Brave does to the pages loaded through it. Having said that I won't be giving you a firm answer on this :)

(PS: if you set up automatic testing it doesn't really matter if you have to test another browser)

Comment: "If you set up automatic testing, it doesn't really matter if you have to test another browser." <- Famous last words :)

Comment: In other words, Brave is Ad/Tracker Blocking Chrome, its simply Chrome but blocks Ads and Trackers. Well Chrome could as well offer the option to turn off trackers and block ads. I really don't know :slightly_smiling: